# How can I use indexOf in array of array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

`let answer = []; let arrA = [[1, 4], [3, 4], [3, 10]] let arrB = [[ 1, 4 ], [1, 10], [ 3, 4], [3, 10]]`

the results of `arrA.indexOf(arrB [i]) == -1`  turn out to be false for all.
How can I solve it?

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+2D+array+indexOf+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```js
let answer = [];
let arrA = [
  [1, 4],
  [3, 4],
  [3, 10]
]
let arrB = [
  [1, 4],
  [1, 10],
  [3, 4],
  [3, 10]
]

for (const a of arrB) {
  const index = arrA.findIndex(o => o[0] === a[0] && o[1] === a[1])
  answer.push(index)
}

console.log(answer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but to make my answer correct, `  if(index== -1){
        answer= a;
  }` this code worked.